# add class if its home page in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If its index then add else remove class in body tag

app.js

```
angular.module('app', [
'ui.router', 
'ngAnimate'
])
.config(
[          '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
    .otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider

    .state("app", {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: 'tmpl/app.html'
    })
    .state('app.about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'tmpl/aboutus.html'

    })
    .state('app.result', {
        url: '/result',
        templateUrl: 'tmpl/search_result.html'

    })
}
]
);
```

index.html

```
<body class="home" ng-class="" >
```

Add class if its Home page abc.com/ else remove the added class, ex: abc.com/#/about

Thanks in advance
Kanagan

Answer (score 1):

There are many options could create a controller for the body to handle this or do this with a directive or service. The easiest option would be to use $rootScope.

```
angular.module('app', [
  'ui.router', 
  'ngAnimate'
])

.run(['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      //console.log(toState);
      $rootScope.home = (toState.name == 'app');
  });
}])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
    .otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state("app", {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: 'tmpl/app.html'
    })
    .state('app.about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'tmpl/aboutus.html'

    })
    .state('app.result', {
        url: '/result',
        templateUrl: 'tmpl/search_result.html'

    })
}]);
```

then in the html...

```
<body class="home" ng-class="{'my-home-class':$root.home}">
```

I didn't test this. If it doesn't work do a console.log on `toState` and see what the value is on different pages and adjust the code as needed.

**UPDATE**

I created a [plunker with a functional example](http://embed.plnkr.co/42Ncs3tm8r2Gcm1Cxskn/preview). I'm not sure what is in your app.html, but the way you have this set up I'd advise adding another state for `app.home` which I created in my example.

Comment: Thanks.
I tried but no luck :(
could you check and help?

Comment: @Kanagan As I mentioned looking at the `console.log` would've shown you what you needed. `toState` is an object containing url, templateUrl, and name. I used `toState.name` to identify which view is showing. I also added a plunker so you can see it in action.